# Percorrer todo o registro

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu conseguir percorrer todo o registro (chaves e subchaves, não precisa o valor delas) do sistema operacional para encontrar o nome de uma chave em especifico?

Se sim, alguém poderia me dizer como fazer no python 3.x+ ou ao menos me indicar um caminho de como fazer isso?

Comment: Se você quer somente certificar-se que uma chave existe, porque percorrer todo o registro? em todo caso, você pode usar a função [`EnumKey`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html#winreg.EnumKey) do módulo `Winreg` para enumerar as chaves.

Comment: Eu quero meio que fazer uma pesquisa pelo registro sem ter um caminho pré definido. Por exemplo: achar a chave x em todo o registro.

Comment: Entendi, você quer encontrar somente a primeira ocorrência ou continuar procurando? talvez recursão seja necessário neste caso.

Comment: A chave seria por acaso o PATH?

Answer (score 1):

O Python dispõe de um módulo para acessar o registro do Windows. Ele vem junto na biblioteca padrão, não é preciso importar nada externo.

```
import winreg
```

Esse módulo possui uma função que recebe uma HKEY e um índice, e retorna o nome da subchave do HKEY naquele índice. Se o índice for inválido, ele libera um WindowsError. Assim é possível obter o nome de todas as subchaves imediatas de uma dada HKEY.

```
def obter_subchaves_imediatas(hkey):
    i = 0

    try:
        while True:
            yield winreg.EnumKey(hkey, i)
            i += 1
    except WindowsError:
        pass
```

Agora, usando a função acima, é fácil escrever uma rotina que navega recursivamente por toda a árvore de registros. É basicamente o algoritmo de navegação pre-order numa árvore qualquer.

```
def navegar_arvore(nome_chave_raiz):
    hkey = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, nome_chave_raiz)

    for nome_subchave in obter_subchaves_imediatas(hkey):
        nome_completo = f'{nome_chave_raiz}\\{nome_subchave}'
        yield nome_completo
        yield from navegar_arvore(nome_completo)
```

Um simples laço permite obter todos os caminhos a partir de uma certa raiz.

```
for chave in navegar_arvore('Control Panel'):
    print(chave)
```

Existem vários pontos que podem ser melhorados neste código, mas o que foi mostrado aqui é suficiente para resolver o problema.